# HTML- Adding and removing to favorites

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating a website and I wanted to know how one would add and remove a page to favorites as I couldn't find much on internet about this. Suppose I have a car page  and I have button on the page called add to favorites or an achor (take a pick). I know the way as you can add using the browser code but I want save the car page on my one of my own created page eg.favorite.html and also making sure that I can only add once to the favourite page. So then I can view the favourite list on the page,look through them and remove/clear properties. So i need help with it , please any help would be great. thanks.

add favorite code using a browser, this code save favorites on browser but i want to do it on a page :

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("#bookmarkme").click(function() {
        // Mozilla Firefox Bookmark
        if ('sidebar' in window && 'addPanel' in window.sidebar) { 
            window.sidebar.addPanel(location.href,document.title,"");
        } else if( /*@cc_on!@*/false) { // IE Favorite
            window.external.AddFavorite(location.href,document.title); 
        } else { // webkit - safari/chrome
            alert('Press ' + (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('mac') != - 1 ? 'Command/Cmd' : 'CTRL') + ' + D to bookmark this page.');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

this is achor tag

```
 <a id="bookmarkme" href="#" rel="sidebar" title="bookmark this page">Save page</a>
```

above code works to save the page in the browser. 
I want to add my favorite page on to another html page of mines .

HELP NEEDED!!

Answer (score 1):

You can make a script that counts the favorites.

Follow these steps to make it work.

Step 1. Create a text file (For example fbp1.txt)
Step 2. Make a PHP Page (For example fbp1.php)
Step 3. Create a page for your blog post (For example Blog1.php)
Step 4. Add this script to the fb1.php file

```
        <?php
//In the spot of fbp1.txt place your file name!
    $count_my_page = ("fbp1.txt");
    $hits = file($count_my_page);
    $hits[0] ++;
    $fp = fopen($count_my_page , "w");
    fputs($fp , "$hits[0]");
    fclose($fp);
// In the spot of Blog1.php place you page name!
    header("Location : Blog1.php")
    ?>
```

Step 5. Create your blog post and add these two codes

Code 1:

```
<img src="/path/to/star.png" href="fbp1.php"/>
```

Code 2:

```
<p> <?php echo file_get_contents('fbp1.txt');?> Favorites </p>
```

When someone clicks the star it add +1 to the text file and it should look like this

[IMAGE OF STAR]
   342 Favorites.

I hoped this helped you out!

Comment: @P.J There you go, please upvote and make it the answer any more questions i'd like to hear!

Answer (score 0):

Short, you can't.

When user clicks to add to favorites button, it is not in the scope of the website anymore. Adding favorites or deleting ones are processed in browser side. Only you can do is counting number of clicks to add to favorites button.

Answer (score 0):

Even tough this is **not** a question i'll try to answer it..

You can't simply do this by html, javascript.

You need PHP and MYSQL. Try to search google for a simple my favorites script.

What you can do it that you have a counter how many times the favorite button is clicked.
Or simple PHP how many people have viewed the post/webpage.

Comment: I havent done PHP and mysql yet. but i have added some up there see if that makes sense

Comment: You can make a star button and than you go to a page like fav_bp1.php and in that page there is a little script that add +1 to a text file, when you return to the post you see Favorites: 1

Comment: If its alright with you , could show it to me on jsfiddle or something like that.

Comment: What, the PHP Script?

Comment: cause i am not exactly clear how to excute the whole process I know sound dumb to ask that, but if you dont mind

Comment: Of course i can help you! I'll make a answer for you :-)